# Do I manually minify css code in my main theme or child theme?

Tags: performance

WordPress developers,

I am using a child theme for my DIVI WordPress theme. I want to use a Minify CSS tool.

Do I first copy all the code from my main theme style.css file into my child theme style.css file or do I minify the code directly in my main theme style.css and if I do this will it still be minified when my theme gets updated?

Comment: if you add minify css in your child theme it will not effect when you update your main theme.

Comment: Are you saying that is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I think no problem... changing anything in child theme not effect in the main theme. So without hesitation you can do that... :)

Comment: "Do I first copy all the code from my main theme style.css file into my child theme style.css" — Never copy _all_ the code from the main theme's stylesheet into the child theme's style sheet. Only copy those elements you need to change.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a light (faster) ecommerce platform and theme to use to replace DIVI and WooCommerce without haveing to build it myself??

Answer (score 2):

I'll be controversial here and point out that if you're using a pre-built theme as massively "heavy" as you are, then honestly I wouldn't even worry about minning CSS files!

I'll go out on a limb and guess you are also using a bunch of plugins (my bunch is 6+) in which case why not just go ahead and install a CSS minning plugin as well, and have done with it?

From an actual devs point of view then sure you can min the code in your child theme for (presumably, there's little of it) minor benefit. Or you can min the CSS in the main theme and get (larger...I bet there's 5k lines+) benefits from doing so - until you update the theme and it "un"mins gain.

Honestly, I would either:

1. Learn to craft you own theme - lean mean, fast to load and professional
2. Use the "divi" theme and forget about it
3. Employ a minning plugin

...in that order :)

The demo here: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Divi shows 12 CSS files and 24 JS files being loaded. So again, I just feel there's a slight disconnect between using a theme like that, and being concerned about load speed. You might as well buy a Ford Fiesta and then worry about entering it into a drag race ;)

Comment: IIRC since the CSS is gona be "zipped" in any case before it is being sent, the actual file size saved is like 10%, which is just not enough saving worth doing manual labor, especially since it is likely a child theme is gona be changed many times. Totally agree with the bottom line, use a plugin or forget about it.

Comment: Yep, & I'll add that, when using Divi or other such heavy themes, the tiny amount you'll save is pointless as you will have a large number of server requests for numerous scripts and plugins etc. Sorting those out is better time spent. but frankly, overall it is better to concentrate on minimising your images since until your images are properly optimised you won't see much improvement in your site speed. use http://webpagetest.org or something similar to highlight what is actually slowing your site down.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a light (faster) ecommerce platform and theme to use to replace DIVI and WooCommerce without haveing to build it myself??